# Function called on dataframe can't index it the right way

Tags: python, pandas, ticker

I am doing a small machine learning project. I have collected all the tickers for the company in the S&P500 in a dataframe along with their daily values. The issue is that when I call the function

```
do_ml('BAC')
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\giuli\Desktop\UDEMY COURSES\finance\Git_rep\processing _for_ml.py", line 87, in <module>
    do_ml('BAC')
  File "c:\Users\giuli\Desktop\UDEMY COURSES\finance\Git_rep\processing _for_ml.py", line 72, in do_ml
    X,y,df = extract_featuresets(ticker)
  File "c:\Users\giuli\Desktop\UDEMY COURSES\finance\Git_rep\processing _for_ml.py", line 46, in extract_featuresets
    df['{}_d1'.format(ticker)],
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2980, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 126, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 152, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 169, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._maybe_get_bool_indexer
KeyError: 'BAC_d1'
```

Thiese are all the functions involved in the function called:

```
def remove_extra_characters(df):
    df.rename(columns={old:old.strip() for old in df.columns}, inplace=True)


def process_data_for_labels(ticker):
    hm_days=7
    df = pd.read_csv('sp500_joined_closes.csv', index_col = 0 )

    tickers = df.columns.values.tolist()
    df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    remove_extra_characters(df)

    for i in range(1, hm_days+1):
        df['{}_{}d'.format(ticker, i)] = (df[ticker].shift(-i) - df[ticker]) / df[ticker]

    print(df)

    df.fillna(0,inplace=True)

    return tickers, df



def buy_sell_hold(*args):
    cols = [c for c in args]
    requirements = 0.02
    for col in cols:
        if col > requirements:
            return 1
        if col < requirements:
            return -1
    return 0

def extract_featuresets(ticker):
    tickers, df = process_data_for_labels(ticker)

    df['{}_target'.format(ticker)] = list(map( buy_sell_hold,
                                               df['{}_d1'.format(ticker)],
                                               df['{}_d2'.format(ticker)],
                                               df['{}_d3'.format(ticker)],
                                               df['{}_d4'.format(ticker)],
                                               df['{}_d5'.format(ticker)],
                                               df['{}_d6'.format(ticker)],
                                               df['{}_d7'.format(ticker)]))

    vals = df['{}target'.format(ticker)].values.tolist()
    str_vals= [str(i) for i in vals]
    print('Data spread:', Counter(str_vals))
    df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

    df = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
    df.dropna(inplace=True)

    df_vals = df[[ticker for ticker in tickers]].pct_change()
    df_vals = df_vals.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0)
    df_vals.fillna(0, inplace=True)

    X = df_vals.values #Percent change data of comanies.
    y = df['{}target'.format(ticker)].values #target

    return X, y, df

def do_ml(ticker):
    X,y,df = extract_featuresets(ticker)
    #setting sets for training and testing giving it 25% of the size each.
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X,
                                                                         y,
                                                                         test_size = 0.25)
    #selecting classifier
    clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()
    #fitting data in classifier
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    confidence = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
    predictions = clf.predict(X_test)
    print('Predicted spread:', Counter(predictions))
    return confidence
```

The issue is definitely in the extract_feature function. What I am doing there is just basically creating 7 columns in my dataframe where each of those holds a value that tries to predict how the price will change for the that day( So the dataframe will be showing the change for every day in the next week)

Comment: KeyError is raised when dict() object is requested and the key is not in the dictionary. To get this fixed use setdefault(key, val) to set the value of the key only if it is not already in the dict

Comment: but there is... I printed the dataframe out and there actually is a column named 'BAC_d1'. That is what is driving me crazy :/